# Google Chrome Extensions as standalone application

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to run a Google Chrome extensions outside of Chrome? For instance, there is an add-on called  TLDR which summarizes text on a web page. Is it possible to write a program that can somehow "tap" into it's summarization capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do it just like so. But since you are on SO and this is about programming, I would suggest to inspect the extension JavaScript code. Extensions are really only JavaScript and if this extension is written in a modular fashion you may be able to get the functions out and use them separately.

Before you do that, you should ask the author of the extension if it is okay with him/her. He/She might even help you with the task if you ask politely :)

Comment: This is not true. My Advanced REST Client extension used to run outside chrome. I remember I simply took the shortcut link from the Chrome Apps Launcher and added it to my windows toolbar. But I am not being able to replicate this behavior. Perhaps because I am working in a Windows Server 2008 R2 ?! no idea...

Comment: But the OP wants to "tap" into the extension results. For that to work you need to code I guess. Nothing is won if it runs as Chrome App instead of a Chrome Extension.

Comment: The question's title suggests he wants to run an extension outside chrome's browser, as a standalone app. Assuming the question reflects the title's desc, then this should be the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but not exactly "outside".

This solution allows you to run a chrome extension as a **standalone window**.

You can create a shortcut with a link to the extension.

**TrustWallet example**

TrustWallet is one of those Apps that do not have a web version and this was the best way to have it as an "App" on Desktop.

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
 --app="chrome-extension://egjidjbpglichdcondbcbdnbeeppgdph/home.html#/"
```

**Bitwarden Password Manager example**

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
--app="chrome-extension://nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb/popup/index.html#/"
```

**How to build the URL?**

On some chrome extensions you have it when clicking the icon in your browser. But, on some other extensions you cannot see it. For them you have to use "Manage Extension" on Chrome. You can find it right-clicking the extension icon or on the extensions section. Extension > Details.

There you can grab the fields:

ID (extension ID)

```
nngceckbapebfimnlniiiahkandclblb
```

Inspect views (this is the viewpathfile)

```
background.html
popup/index.html
```

Usually is the one named index.html or home.html that points to the main view of the extension

**Build the extension url**

```
chrome-extension://id/viewpathfile#/
```

**Isolate Functionality**

Now, if you want to only access the capabilities of the *extension code* you need to find the Github/Repository open source project and isolate the functionality you are looking for.

You can convert it to command line if needed, but that is a case by case situation.